# Can't import installed scala/sbt library dependency from github

Tags: scala, sbt

I need to install some dependencies in my simplest scala project (I am passing some tutorial) and one of them is from github. My `build.sbt` looks like this:

```
import sbt._

lazy val root = Project("root", file("."))
    .dependsOn(smile)
    .settings(
        name := "Xyclade ML practical examples",
        version := "1.0",
        scalaVersion := "2.10.6",
        sbtVersion := "0.13.9",
        libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.10.2"
    )

lazy val smile = ProjectRef(uri("https://github.com/haifengl/smile.git#master"), "root")
```

Maybe, I am missing some basic scala/sbt knowledge (I am a complete noob), but:

1) `import com.github.haifengl._` fails with `object github is not a member of package com`

2) `import smile._` leads to error `not found: object smile`

And as far as I found out, the library package should be called something like `com.github.haifengl`: https://github.com/haifengl/smile/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=com.github.haifengl&type=Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure package `com.github.haifengl` is in github project you've mentioned? Could it be in some of it's dependencies?

You should not add `ProjectRef` to github project, instead you'd better add it to dependencies:

```
"com.github.haifengl" % "smile-core" % "1.0.4"
```

Like following:

```
import sbt._

lazy val root = Project("root", file("."))
    .settings(
        name := "Xyclade ML practical examples",
        version := "1.0",
        scalaVersion := "2.10.6",
        sbtVersion := "0.13.9",
        libraryDependencies += Seq(
                "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.10.2",
                 "com.github.haifengl" % "smile-core" % "1.0.4"
    )
```

Comment: @mr-v , that's worked, thanks! I can import lib by calling `import smile._`. But I can't use any classes from it, for example `val plot = ScatterPlot...` fails with `not found: value ScatterPlot`. Or I should explicitly declare the class somewhere in Scala?

Comment: Fixed this by `import smile.plot._` (sry for such silly mistakes). Thanks a lot, again!